# Test for the presence of only one hyphen in the account number

Tags: java, oop

I would like to rewrite the following code using only String methods, without for loops.

```
// Run the QuestionGenerator and test for the error condition 
// indicated. If the account number has a valid format 
// according to the requirement set out in the question generator, return
// true, otherwise false.

private static boolean isAccountFormatCorrect(String name)  {
    int m = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
        char a = name.charAt(i); 
        if (a == '-') { 
            m++; 
        }
    } 

    if (m >= 2) { 
        throw new BadAccountInputException("Only one hyphen allowed in account number");
    }
     
    return true;
}
```

Comment: So what's your question? Give us samples of what you tried doing and what you got.

Comment: Also, you never return false - instead, you're throwing an exception. You can also just check if there are multiple hyphens in your for loop itself, using a boolean telling you if it's already encountered one. Another way to do it would be to find the first and last index of `-` in the string, and make sure they're equal.

Comment: Use String.indexOf('-') and String.lastIndexOf('-')

Answer (score 1):

Compare the first index of a hyphen with the last index where it is found. If they are equal, then there was only one.

```
private static boolean isAccountFormatCorrect(String name)  {
    if(name.indexOf('-') != name.lastIndexOf('-')){
      throw new BadAccountInputException("Only one hyphen allowed in account number");
    }
    return true;
}
```

However, it seems you want to return a boolean indicating whether or not the account is valid, in which case there is no need to throw exceptions.

```
private static boolean isAccountFormatCorrect(String name)  {
    return name.indexOf('-') == name.lastIndexOf('-');
}
```

If you need to ensure there exactly one hyphen, you will need to check that the index of not -1.

```
private static boolean isAccountFormatCorrect(String name)  {
    int idx = name.indexOf('-');
    return idx != -1 && idx == name.lastIndexOf('-');
}
```

Comment: A better way to do it would be just `return name.indexOf('-') != name.lastIndexOf('-')`. No need to throw exceptions - that violates the method contract.

Comment: @user Indeed, it is better to not throw any exception in this case.

Comment: If the String has no dashes, your test returns true.  -1 == -1.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc So would the method written in the question.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I think they mean one hyphen max instead of exactly one hyphen. Still, it wouldn't hurt to add one for the other case too, hev1.

Comment: @user All right.